# ag-grid setColumnVisible can't show/hide row group columns?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Was not able to find out if ag-grid had the functionality, so trying to emulate something similar to how a Tableau report will hide or show the next grouping column depending on if the previous column row group is expanded or not. I have column definitions to toggle the row grouping, and the remainder of the column groups in which they are linked like so:

```
colDefs = [
{ showRowGroup: 'col_A', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer', headerName: 'Column A', hide: false },
{ showRowGroup: 'col_B', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer', headerName: 'Column B', hide: true },
{ showRowGroup: 'col_C', cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer', headerName: 'Column C', hide: true },
{ headerName: 'Column A', field: 'col_A', rowGroup: true, hide: true },
{ headerName: 'Column B', field: 'col_B', rowGroup: true, hide: true },
{ headerName: 'Column C', field: 'col_C', rowGroup: true, hide: true },
{ headerName: 'Column D', field: 'col_D', hide: false },
];
```

Column A, B, and C can be expanded to show the child rows. The definition shows that only the first group column Column A is displayed at first, alongside the detail data (in which I have a renderer to display a sum).

I set onRowGroupOpened in the grid options to detect opening and collapsing of a row group, in which I would like to show Column B and Column C respectively on expansion, so I used setColumnVisible, but passing the column object or key (such as 'col_B') will cause the non-group column with field: 'col_B' to show (colDef[4]) instead of the agGroupCellRenderer column def (colDef[1]).

Issue would be fixed if possible to set visibility by index instead of field name.

Trying to find a workaround, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution shortly after I posted the question.

setColumnVisible is referring to a 'colId' property of the column you want to show/hide, and this is automatically set to the field name for the normal columns, but for the row group columns it was being set to string numbers - "0", "1", "2". Was able to use those as the key to show and hide the columns.